# Unable to call the fit function on randomforest regressor python sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm unable to call the fit function on the RandomForestRegressor and even the intellisense is only showing the predict and some other parameters. Below is my code, traceback call and an image showing the content of the intellisense.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
def predict():
    Fvector = 'C:/Users/Oussema/Desktop/Cred_Data/VEctors/FinalFeatureVector.csv'
    data = np.genfromtxt(Fvector, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)
    AnnotArr = np.array(data['CredAnnot']) #this is a 1D array containig   the ground truth (50000 rows)
    TempTestArr = np.array([data['GrammarV'],data['TweetSentSc'],data['URLState']]) #this is the features vector the shape is (3,50000) the values range is [0-1]
    FeatureVector = TempTestArr.transpose() #i used the transpose method to get the shape (50000,3)
    RF_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, max_features = 'auto', n_jobs = -1)
    RF_model.fit(FeatureVector,AnnotArr)
    print(RF_model.oob_score_)
predict()
```

Intelisense content:
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XweOo.png

Traceback call

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oussema\source\repos\Regression_Models\Regression_Models\Random_forest_TCA.py", line 15, in <module>
predict()
File "C:\Users\Oussema\source\repos\Regression_Models\Regression_Models\Random_forest_TCA.py", line 14, in predict
print(RF_model.oob_score_)
AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'oob_score_'
```

Comment: Your problem is not with `fit`, but with `oob_score_` method

Comment: Yeah you are right my issue turned out to be related to oob_score_ method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `oob_score` param to `True` when initializing the RandomForestRegressor.

As per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html):

> oob_score : bool, optional (default=False)
>
> ```
> whether to use out-of-bag samples to estimate the R^2 on unseen data.
> ```

So the attribute `oob_score_` is only available if you do this:

```
def predict():
    ....
    ....
    RF_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, 
                                     max_features = 'auto', 
                                     n_jobs = -1, 
                                     oob_score=True)  #<= This is what you want
    ....
    ....
    print(RF_model.oob_score_)
```